# How do I put a facade around an NHibernate Entity that has mapped collections?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

As an example, imagine a mapped entity called Customer that has a property for a list of Orders.

I want to write a class that adapts Customer to a SpecialCustomer, and SpecialCustomer will have a property called SpecialOrders that adapts/wraps the Customer's list of Orders.

Can anyone think of a way to do this without breaking NHibernate's lazy load semantics?  If I subclass Customer and have my SpecialOrders property return Orders.Cast() I believe its going to have to iterate through all of the items in the Orders property (which I don't want), and I would prefer not to expose an Orders property in SpecialCustomer at all if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure, maybe [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this using `List<T>` as the generic type needs to be two way and you cannot have both covariance and contravariance combined.

How about mapping a protected property `List<Order> OrdersCore` and on Customer exposing `IEnumerable<Order> Orders` property and on SpecialCustomer exposing `IEnumerable<SpecialOrder> SpecialOrders`. The latter would simply use OrdersCore.Cast(). This will not cause the list to be iterated unnecessarily unless the caller does so. The cost would be minlmal. Down side is you will have to provide methods on each class for AddOrder() etc. with the appropriate parameter type.

Comment: But it will still cause the entire list to be iterated and cast if I want to do something like customer.SpecialOrders.Count().  Unless I am mistaken, doesn't NHibernate just replace that with a count query, instead of pulling all of the data from the collection?

Comment: You are mistaken. Accessing a lazy loaded collection for any reason will load the collection.